# issues with hamburger menu bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, hamburger-menu

i have class for replacing my class container i called it container-mini
so far good not problem but when, in the mobile screen it have problem on hamburger menu like this
[image: fail hamburger menu]
here my simple header code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light my-4" id="navna">
    <div class="container-mini">
       <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#site-nav" aria-controls="site-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand logona" href="/dusbam/id/"> 
           <h1>LOGO</h1>
       </a>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="site-nav">
           <ul class="navbar-nav text-sm-left ml-auto">
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="/dusbam/id/rooms">Kamar</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

but when i replace container-mini with container it's fine like this
[image: good hamburger menu]

so my question is how to make hamburger menu like pict 2 without class container

Comment: What does your `.container-mini` class look like?

Comment: can you share your `css` code?

Comment: Seems to be a width problem.  Not sure because there is no css to proof it, but you logo seems to break down because there are no space on his sites. I guess that, or the hamburger menu is position absolute, or it width is smaller than your custom class.

Comment: I used class container-mini for change all class container beacause i want customizing the size of width, so in css code container-mini:{width:123px}

Comment: Fyi all position are relative

Comment: can you please share live link of the website?